# Creating external pthreads with pthread's .text received remotely

Tags: pthreads, external

I want to create a pthread with the pthread's function received remotely.
so that the pthread will be compiled separately from the main code and I store it in a known memory location. 
when I create the pthread from the main static thread, I only pass the memory location of the   pthread's .text without having the pthread's text written in the main code

I'm not experienced with multi-threading. is this idea correct and is there any special instructions or directives that i should use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally done by linkage.

```
/* source file 1*/
#include <pthread.h>

extern void *thread(void *); /* better yet, put this in a common header file */
/* ... */
int main(void)
{
   int err;
   pthread_t thread_id;
   /* ... */
   err = pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, &thread, 0);
   /* ... */
}

/* source file 2 */
void thread(void *)
{
  /* ... */
}
```

You separately compile the files and link together. The linking process ensures that the `thread` reference in the first file is resolved to the address of the `thread` function in the other source file.

Comment: Thanks, this had worked. now i have two object files, one for the main code and second one for the pthread, however they are still combined into one ELF. and I its not clear to me what is the memory address to which the pthread pointer is pointing to. I want to be able to define where the main static thread should create and run the new pthread ( something like extern void* partial_sum_worker(void *) will be located in the memory address 0x50000000) and second, would kindly clarify more about the linking process so that pthread is spereated fro the main ELF

Comment: If you want to run code at an arbitrary numeric address, you can just cast an integer value to a function pointer, e.g. `(void * (*)(void *)) 0x50000000)`, as in:  `pthread_create(&id, 0, (void *(*)(void *)) 0x50000000, 0);`